# File persistence in docker container, Error: EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted

Tags: node.js, docker, file-upload, containers, volumes

I'm studying a way to persist photo file that are sent via nodejs api. I can save normally, but when I recreate the images I lose all saved images. Can you tell me what to study to solve this?, thanks.

I generate the image with a dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./ 
RUN yarn install 
COPY . 
EXPOSE 3333 
ENTRYPOINT sh /app/start.sh
```

and running like this:
docker run --name server-dev -v server_api_uploads:/app/tmp/uploads -p 3333:3333 server_image

It's giving this error:

[Error: EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted, rename '/app/tmp/24f6947d857e33c1a554-foto.png' -> '/app/tmp/uploads/24f6947d857e33c1a554-foto.png'] { errno: -18, code: 'EXDEV', syscall: 'rename', path: '/app/tmp/24f6947d857e33c1a554-foto.png', dest: '/app/tmp/uploads/24f6947d857e33c1a554-foto.png' }

Comment: Looking into Docker volumes to persist data may be helpful: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/.  And if you need persistence in local filesystem: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: Unable to run with nodejs.

Comment: I don't understand "Unable to run with nodejs". Unable to run what with node.js?  The docs I linked are language agnostic and issues you're having appear to be language agnostic.

Comment: Sorry for my English.

Comment: No worries! If you can add some clarity or maybe examples of how you're using/running Docker, what your node.js in the container is doing, and what your goal is, that could help answerers help you.

Comment: Could you please edit the question to include these details? A little hard to read in the comments. Thanks!